# Unexpected behavior of cond statement

Tags: scheme, conditional-statements

I need to write the function which works this way: if its argument is less than 3, it has to return the argument, otherwise it returns `f(n-1) + f(n-2) + f(n-3)`. The function has to generate iterative (not recursive) process.
Now, I have this variant of my function:

```
(define (fi n)
    (define (fiHelper x1 x2 x3 c)
        (cond ((= c 2) x3)
            (else (fiHelper x2 x3 (+ x1 x2 x3) (- c 1)))))
    (cond ((< n 3) n)
        (else fiHelper 0 1 2 n)))
```

It always returns me the n which I've passed into it, no matter what I pass, for example it returns `10` if I've passed `10`, it returns `17` if I've passed `17` and so on. I've rewritten it with `if` statement like so:

```
(define (fi n)
    (define (fiHelper x1 x2 x3 c)
        (cond ((= c 2) x3)
            (else (fiHelper x2 x3 (+ x1 x2 x3) (- c 1)))))
    (if (< n 3) 
        n
        (fiHelper 0 1 2 n)))
```

And it works as expected - returns `230` for the n equals `10`. I can't figure out what's the difference between `cond` and `if` which causes this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `(else (fiHelper 0 1 2 n))`, not `(else fiHelper 0 1 2 n)`. The first expression calls the helper function; the second one just evaluates the symbols `fiHelper, 0, 1, 2`, taking the value of the last one.

Comment: Pair of parentheses... It was THAT simple. Thank you for a quick response!

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code was for I not so easy to find. I inserted a "(display "HelferFoo") in the foo fiHelper and noticed then that this foo was never called.

Georg Fuss